# Custom Validation if FileUpload is Empty my message is show

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

```
This is my `.aspx` for `FileuUpload` ..
<asp:FileUpload  ID="FileUpload1"  runat="server" class="multi form-control"   /> 
<asp:CustomValidator ID="ValidatorUpload" runat="server" ErrorMessage="File Upload Tidak boleh kosong" ControlToValidate="FileUpload1" Display="Dynamic" OnServerValidate="ValidatorUpload_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

And this my `.aspx.cs`(Code behind).

```
protected void ValidatorUpload_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        FileUpload Upload = (FileUpload)FormView1.FindControl("FileUpload1");
        HttpPostedFile hpf = Upload.PostedFile;
        if (((CustomControls_DdlLocation)FormView1.Controls[0].FindControl("ddl_location1")).SelectedText.ToLower().Trim() == "kelanis")
        {

            if (hpf.FileName == null)
            {
                args.IsValid = false;
            }
            else
            {
                args.IsValid = true;

            }

        }

    }
```

I want to show message if `FileUpload` is `Empty` but my code isn't working.
Need a Solution to this.

Comment: Please specify the exact error or issue that you are encountering in this regard

Comment: this issue my message or notification is not show

Answer (score 1):

I have used this one. Works perfactly

```
 <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:requiredfieldvalidator errormessage="Required" controltovalidate="FileUpload1"
                                runat="server" display="Dynamic" forecolor="Red" />
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ValidationExpression="([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.doc|.docx|.pdf)$"
                                    ControlToValidate="FileUpload1" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Please select a valid Word or PDF File file."
                                    Display="Dynamic" />
    <br />
    <asp:button text="Submit" runat="server" />
```

For Images you can use the following regular expression validator

```
([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.png|.jpg|.gif)$
```

Thanks

Comment: You can use ValidatorEnable($("[id$='FileUpload1']")[0], false); while skipping.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this

```
if (hpf.HasFile == false)
{
    if ( hpf.FileName != "")
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: oke sir but if i use hpf.text my error show this 'System.Web.HttpPostedFile' does not contain a definition for 'text' and no extension method 'text' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFile' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You can use File name instead of text.

Comment: oke sir but if use hpf.HasFile my error show error again " CS1061: 'System.Web.HttpPostedFile' does not contain a definition for 'HasFile' and no extension method 'HasFile' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFile' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Answer (score 1):

Please use try this

```
protected void checkfilesize(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        string data = args.Value;
        args.IsValid = false;
        double filesize = FileUpload1.FileContent.Length;
        if (filesize > 5000)
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
        else
        {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: no , i want is show message if FileUpload null or empty. before my code already for only image and filesize validation.

Comment: You can chech the length of Fileupload if(FileUpload1.FileContent.Length > 0 ) like this.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this solution

```html
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvDocument" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Upload your file!" ValidationGroup="NewDocument" ControlToValidate="fuDocument" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
 <asp:FileUpload ID="fuDocument" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload File" ValidationGroup="NewDocument" />
```

and in server code remember to put in button code that will start to save the file this:

```
    Me.Validate("NewDocument");
    If (Me.IsValid) { 
     //your code
     }
```

Comment: Good Working, but is not i want